# NSRulerView Color

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am using `NSRulerView` in my app and my interface is not like default `NSRulerView` Color.

```
NSRulerView *_verticalRuler;
NSRulerView *_horizontalRuler;
```

This is interface declarations and I am using `_verticalRuler` and `_horizontalRuler` in my code to where to show.

Now I need a subclass of `NSRulerView` with another my own background color and text color. Does anybody know how to write a subclass of `NSRulerView` to change it's background and text color?

Thanks for your help.

Mediajon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much in the way of customisation; this *does not look easy*! But could try this. Subclass NSRulerView and override `-drawHashMarksAndLabelsInRect:` you will have to do all the custom drawing for the marks and labels. To get some inspiration for what exactly you will have to do to implement the custom drawing take a look  at the [gnustep project's NSRulerView](https://github.com/gnustep/libs-gui/blob/master/Source/NSRulerView.m#L616). As part of the drawing you can create attributed strings, try changing the the font colour and background there.

Comment: Link not available anymore.

Comment: The project's name changed from `gnustep-gui` to `libs-gui` so the new link is https://github.com/gnustep/libs-gui/blob/master/Source/NSRulerView.m#L616